# Strange applications are being installed sometimes

Tags: applications, 5.1-lollipop, installation, unknown-sources

I am using Android 5.1 and there is strange thing.Sometimes, when I am connected to wifi apps are being installed without permissions.When I go to settings and uncheck 'Allow installing apps from sources different to google play store' I have no idea how, but after around hour it is being marked as checked and new app is being installed.

I tryed installing anti virus programs like AVG's mobile version, Avast's mobile version, Malwarbytes and others..Do you have any ideas how to fix that, without reseting phone's fabric settings.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Not sure your carrier, but some use DT Ignite which will do this.  Happened on my Verizon S7 Edge.  Go to Settings - Application Manager, browse the list and look for "DT Ignite" and Disable it if you see it.

Answer (score 0):

- backup important data
- do factory reset

if your device is rooted or the factory reset didn't work:

- search for a complete factory image for this specific device model (also known as ROM)
- flash it. (or if scared, find someone who is willing to do it)

Anything else would be a half measure, but if you really want to avoid resetting:

- check if the attached Google account is compromised, because it's possible to install apps remotely via Google play.
- Another possibility is some applications which got "device administrator" permission, so you can first find "device administrators" in settings and make sure that there are no device administrators.

Comment: I tryed this, but it doesn't worked.I mean the apps are still being installed.Maybe there is an app, which controlls device..

Comment: what exactly did you try?

Comment: Well, I installed antivirus softwares and scanned it.